# Help finding replacement parts?

Tags: components, replacement

My mum's sewing machine released its magic smoke, and while I'm reasonably adept with a soldering iron, I don't have sufficient experience with electronic components to do this all on my own.

I have identified one blown <strike>electrolyte(?)</strike> cap and two other that I also want to replace now that I'm at it. There are two identical 0.1uF and one 0.01uF (edit: corrected 'milli' to 'micro'.

Here are pictures -- can you help me find an online store where I can buy replacement components? Thank you!

[image]

This is one of the 0.1mF -- it says "PME 271 M610". I can get no good reading of the smaller type.
[image] [image]

Comment: ugh, Rifa. Never seen a single Rifa capacitor that's not at least close to breaking. Even if one of them is reading correctly, replace it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are NOT electrolytic capacitors! Electrolytic capacitors would blow up when connected to mains.

These caps are mains input filter caps, so they must be special AC mains rated X class safety capacitors and you must replace them with similar X class capacitors. In the photo, all three caps are marked with an "X" to make it clear what kind of caps they are.

They also are not rated in mF, which means millifarads. They are rated in microfarads and there is a 1000x difference between millifarads and microfarads.

In fact asking what to buy and where is off-topic so I won't answer that part. I just needed to make sure you don't do anything dangerous, as you clearly had no clue how to repair that safely. Have it repaired by a service technician who knows how to repair mains voltage devices.

Comment: A couple of points. 1) Thank you for setting me straight with regards to type. 2) Thank you for info on X rating. 3) Thank you for not close voting but instead giving me a valuable answer.

Comment: Also, the 'micro' was mostly a typo/brain fart, I would have realized before ordering anything.